# Issue with specific version of IE/ Edge browsers ("Session_Start" event is triggered)

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, forms-authentication, global-asax

I am facing a strange issue in a particular version of IE/ Edge browsers (Ex:- IE 11.0.9600.19329).
The issue is, when I click on 'Ctrl+P' on a specific page in my application **"Session_Start"** event gets fired, which is not happening in other browsers. I have verified different forums, but couldn't find any solution.
Any suggestion to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce the problem, it works well on my side. Try to reset the browser setting ([IE browser](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/17441/windows-internet-explorer-change-reset-settings) and [Edge browser](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/reset-microsoft-edge-browser-to-default-settings-in-windows-10)), if still meet this issue, try to upgrade the browser version and using the latest version.

Comment: Identified the issue.

We are displaying an image  in <asp:Image> and the src set from code-behind, like 
Image.ImageUrl = Page.ResolveUrl("~/View/SampleImage.aspx?id=" + userID);

The issue occurs in this scenario.

Any suggestions?

@Zhi Lv - MSFT

Comment: You could try to use web services or Web API to get the image resource, then bind to the image control. Besides, you could also use html image tag, and using Javascript to JQuery Ajax to get the image resource, then set the image value.

Comment: On our legacy site, we're finding that any use of a httphandler is enough to cause the Session_Start to be fired, which is a pain given that we use them for css/js/etc. The suspicion is it's caused by: CVE-2020-0674